# Problem with positioning more fixed elements

Tags: css, layout, positioning, css-position

I'm trying to position correctly more fixed elements [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RnsJ/10/) but it seems that I don't understand enough how to combine `left, right, top, bottom, width, height` to display the element where I want.

Could you please look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare top for the left id because its overlapping the header one, this is why you cant see the left div.

```
top: 40px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Chumillas/7RnsJ/11/

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp